# supportedInterfaceOrientations not working

Tags: ios, orientation

I want some of my ViewControllers landscape and some portrait so this is what I did:

I enabled landscape mode:

[image]

Next I added these lines of code to the view controllers I wanted to be Portrait:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

However when I rotate them they still go to landscape mode.How can I fix that?

Comment: you probably have these methods inside your viewControllers, which are pushed into UINavigationController, right ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is how I do it. 
 
Make a UINavigationController parent class. 
inside you UINavigationController (parent) override these methods like:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if([self.topViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(supportedInterfaceOrientationsForThisContorller)])
    {
        return(NSInteger)[self.topViewController performSelector:@selector(supportedInterfaceOrientationsForThisContorller) withObject:nil];
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if([self.visibleViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldAutorotateNow)])
    {
        BOOL autoRotate = (BOOL)[self.visibleViewController
                            performSelector:@selector(shouldAutorotateNow)
                            withObject:nil];
        return autoRotate;

    }
    return NO;
}
```

Now your NavigationController should be a subclass of the UINavigationContorller parent

**Swift 3:**

Inside your UINavigationController subclass do this

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        get {
            return self.topViewController?.supportedInterfaceOrientations ?? .all
        }
    }

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return self.topViewController?.shouldAutorotate ?? false
    }
```

**Update**
Taken from Matt's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27623947/1363997) if you don't want to subclass:

first: make your viewController a delegate of the navigationController in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.navigationController?.delegate = self
```

Then declare UIViewController extension to respond to the delegate method as shown below:

```
extension UIViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    public func navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations(_ navigationController: UINavigationController) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return navigationController.topViewController?.supportedInterfaceOrientations
    }
}
```

Comment: Put that in my View Controller?

Comment: Or create a custom navigation controller?

Comment: No, this is inside the UINavigationController class, create instance of this class, then push your viewControllers

Comment: @AbdullahShafique, yes exactly

Comment: notice that in UIViewControllers I added - (BOOL)shouldAutoRotateNow, just in case other classes will handle the same methods, so only classes with this method name can respond

Comment: This is unconventional: @Matt's answer is better: use Apple's provided function in UINavigationControllerDelegate to implement this behaviour.

Comment: @ChrisHatton have you tried Matt answer and did it work ?

Answer (score 25):

The Apple designed way to do this for `UINavigationController` is via `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

Usually I just update this delegate to do the following and delegate it to the top displaying controller in the navigation controller's stack:

```
#pragma mark - UINavigationControllerDelegate

- (NSUInteger)navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
{
    return [navigationController.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}
```

In my opinion the `UINavigationController` should just default to the above behavior but this is the api Apple has provided :)

As for the info plist file I uncheck all of the options and handle it all in code as it has caused issues for me in the past and I got tired of dealing with it.

Comment: This method isn't called in my code.  My parent class which is responsible for presenting the view controller is the one that implements UINavigationControllerDelegate, and yet... nope, not called.

Answer (score 20):

For simplicity, for iPad, if *Supported interface orientations (iPad)* property in info.plist includes all the four orientations, with *UIRequiresFullScreen* property value as *NO*, iOS will treat your app as supporting split view. If an app supports split view feature, you can not disable it from rotating, at least by the ways above.

---

Let's go deep into details.

First, we need to know which factors will influence the screen orientation:

**1. Project settings（info.plist）**

There are two places we can do this setting:

- Project->Target->General->Device Orientation

  [image: screen orientation setting in project setting]
- info.plist of the project

  [image: screen orientation setting in info.plist]

The two methods are the same and one will automatically sync the other setting.
In info.plist file, *Supported interface orientations (iPad)* property is for iPad setting (choose *iPad* for *Device* section), and *Supported interface orientations* property is for iPhone and Univeral (choose *iPhone* or *Universal* for *Device* section, and these two settings will always be the same.).

**2. Set supported screen orientations programmatically**

There are two ways to configure the supported orientations while coding:

- `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` method in `UIApplicationDelegate`
- `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method in `UIViewController`

The iOS system will check the common orientations defined in the two methods and use the common orientations as the supported orientations for the view controller.

**3. Set `shouldAutorotate` property in `UIViewController`**

This is a read-only property and used for control if the view controller is rotatable or not. You can override the property in your view controller, or even change the property to read-write property, so that you can modify the property while your app is running. For example:

```swift
override public var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    get {
        return self.shouldAutorotateVariable
    }
    set {
        self.shouldAutorotateVariable = newValue
    }
}
```

`shouldAutorotateVariable` is a private property in your view controller.

### iPhone

If a view controller's `shouldAutorotate` property is set to `false`, iOS will omit the following settings:

- `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` method in `UIApplicationDelegate`
- `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method in `UIViewController`

iOS will only use Project settings (info.plist).

If the `shouldAutorotate` property is not overriden or is set to `true`, then iOS will use the common orientations defined in the following two methods:

- `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` method in `UIApplicationDelegate`
- `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method in `UIViewController`

If the above two methods are not supplied, iOS will use the Project settings (info.plist).

### iPad

From iOS9, iPad supports split view feature. Refer to [Slide Over and Split View Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/QuickStartForSlideOverAndSplitView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015145-CH13-SW1) for the setting of split view.

For simplicity, if *Supported interface orientations (iPad)* property in info.plist includes all the four orientations, with *UIRequiresFullScreen* property value as *NO*, iOS will treat your app as supporting split view. If the app supports split view, the following two settings will be omitted:

- `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` method in `UIApplicationDelegate`
- `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method in `UIViewController`

The `shouldAutorotate` property in `UIViewController` will also be omitted.

That is to say, if an app supports split view feature, you can not disable it from rotating, at least by the ways above.

If *Supported interface orientations (iPad)* property in info.plist value doesn't include all four orientations, or *UIRequiresFullScreen* property is set to *YES*, the app will not support split view, and the screen orientation control logic is the same with iPhone above.

> Note: for the *Project settings (info.plist)*, it's better to set the following three properties directly inside info.plist:
>
> - Supported interface orientations (iPad)
> - Supported interface orientations
> - UIRequiresFullScreen
>
> It is confusing if you try to set through *Project->Target->General->Device Orientation*: even *Device* is set as *Universe*, the setting in *iPad* will still take effect.

Answer (score 3):

Just for you all information, 
create a new project single view based Application, 
implement the should auto rotate delegate and the supportedInterface orientation in viewController 
add breakpoint in it.

The run (universal mode)

1. on iphone simulator :  execution stops at breakpoints
2. on ipad Simulator : executions DOESN'T STOP (delegate methods are never called !!!!)
3. on ipad device : ok

So don't waste too mush time on it like I juste Did, **XCode 7.3 is BUGGED**

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same issue right now - working with iPhone bot not iPad

Comment: @jeyben there is nothing to solve as far as I can see, it's just a simulator bug. try on real device everything should work fine

Answer (score 1):

When under UINavigationController, I'm implementing the UINavigationControllerDelegate and the following method:

```
#pragma mark - From UINavigationControllerDelegate

-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask) navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:(UINavigationController*)navigationController {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; // TODO: change to whatever you need to allow
}
```

Comment: Is there one as well for autoRotate? I did this, and it's properly called to portrait only, but my status bar still rotates in landscape

Answer (score 0):

You can see the answer in the following post:

[iOS 6 rotations: supportedInterfaceOrientations doesn´t work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410031/ios-6-rotations-supportedinterfaceorientations-doesnt-work)

Let me know if it's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case above solution not works then in case if you are using `UITabBarController` then you need to subclass `UITabBarController` and need to override following methods

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
```

I suggest you to use `.all` for `iPad` here is extended

```
 override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
     return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone ? [.portrait, .portraitUpsideDown] : .all

   }
```

Hope helpful someone facing the same issue