# How to disable specific orientation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, landscape-portrait, orientation-changes

I want to disable landscape orientation in some view.

I have overridden the following two methods but these method is not going to call at any time.

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation) preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Am I missing something?
Please help me.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785767/supportedinterfaceorientations-not-working

Comment: You can do it through interface builder.

Comment: @DheerajSingh, That prevents. As I want. But what if I want to support landscape orientation in some of push viewController?

Comment: @AshokLondhe I mention that, I want to prevent only on some of view. Through interface builder either i can disable for all or enable for or.

Comment: There is different orientation for Each view controller. You can it in Interface builder. There is Orientation property of Every ViewController and you can set it manually.

Comment: @AshokLondhe, Can you show me? How can I set for each view Controller? I am using .xib file

Comment: Actually we can set it for each view controller. but i don't know it is working or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create subclass of UINavigationController and override these methods as per below:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if([self.topViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(supportedInterfaceOrientationsForThisContorller)])
    {
        return(NSInteger)[self.topViewController performSelector:@selector(supportedInterfaceOrientationsForThisContorller) withObject:nil];
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if([self.visibleViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldAutorotateNow)])
    {
        BOOL autoRotate = (BOOL)[self.visibleViewController
performSelector:@selector(shouldAutorotateNow)
                                 withObject:nil];
        return autoRotate;
    }
    return YES;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

and use  below method in your UIViewController class where you want to set only portrait orientation

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientationsForThisContorller {
    // Return a bitmask of supported orientations. If you need more,
    // use bitwise or (see the commented return).
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    // return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateNow
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260261/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-not-being-called-in-ios-6) answer. The guy has probably explained the delegates in much detail.

Also try,

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                 selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                 object:nil];
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) &&
        !isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DisplayAlternateView" sender:self];
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
    }
    else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation) &&
             isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: This method is deprecated in iOS 6. So I can not use this method

Comment: This method is not being called at time of orientation change.

Comment: Yes I'm using notifications for changing orientation. Though that I can detect orientation. But how can I prevent??

Answer (score 0):

Did you used below method in your code, with out this supportedInterfaceOrientations will not get called

> -(BOOL) shouldAutorotate 
>   {
>
> ```
> return YES;
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Yes that is written by me

Comment: Well if you are using Nav Controller this must work then, otherwise if this is inside a subview only root will receive this method call. Also check orientation support set properly in info plist.