# App can auto rotate to landscape from portrait on iPad but not on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, screen-orientation

I would like to make ViewController A portrait and   ViewController B landscape. When it runs, all goes portrait even I set app delegate to change as landscape. Would you please tell what to do exactly?  The below is my working ..

ViewController A going to view controller B :

```
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        appDelegate.restrictRotation = TRUE;


        MapViewController * sliderVC =      [[MapViewController alloc] init ];

        sliderVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
        [self presentViewController:sliderVC animated:NO completion:nil];
        sliderVC.view.backgroundColor =  [UIColor clearColor];
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if(self.restrictRotation)//set the bool value to view controller which you want to load in landscape
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Check General tab in the target settings: there is Device Orientation checkboxes. Do you support the required orientation?

Comment: I have made Portrait checked and Landscape checked , not working

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are supporting the wanted orientation:

Project > Target > General

[image]

Comment: I have ticked all these but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

You should override the following methods on View Controller B:

```
func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool
func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int
func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation
```

The method you overrode in the AppDelegate is meant for your entire app.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotate)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you taking a look at the related documentation.

[Multiple Orientations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html)

Basically this is what you need to do for all the view controllers:

```
#pragma mark Orientation handling

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Comment: I have tried But to no avail . Please see this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31244891/ios-force-landscape-in-one-viewcontroller