# Custom Orientations on a specific view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, screen-orientation

I have many view controllers in my app (which supports all orientations). Some of those view controllers have content that is too much to fit in landscape. How can I limit some of my views to portrait while also having some portrait and landscape.

P.S. I'm using objective-C, and i've seen a lot of swift answers but I'm not good at translating Swift->Obj-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your view controller hierarchy is set up.

For example, if you have a `UINavigationController` as your window's `rootViewController`, you can have a [`UINavigationControllerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html) which returns the navigation controller's `topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations`. Then in your portrait-only view controllers, you would return `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPotrait` in `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, and `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll` in the rest of your view controllers.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27623947/1812788

Comment: I tried to do `- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}` but that did nothing. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Do you use a UINavigationController as `window.rootViewController` ? Because in that case, you need a delegate for that navigation controller and implement `- navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:` by querying the navigation controller's `topViewController` for supported orientations. The `UINavigationController` won't do that by default. (see the attached StackOverflow link)