# How to prevent ARSCNView from rotating during orientation change

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit, arscnview

I am using ARKit and I want to allow the users to use the app in both portrait and landscape mode.
I would like all UI controls to rotate on orientation change except for the `ARSCNView`.
I tried to transform the sceneView in the opposite direction but that didn't work.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        let targetRotation = coordinator.targetTransform
        let inverseRotation = targetRotation.inverted()

        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
            self.sceneView.transform = self.sceneView.transform.concatenating(inverseRotation)
            context.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from)
        }, completion: nil)

    }
```

How can I prevent the scene view of the ARKit session from rotating while allowing all other UI controls to rotate on orientation change?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/1015208/praveen-gowda-i-v Did you solve this? I am looking for same..

Comment: @yaali no, wasn't able to find anything to achieve it

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: At one point I saw rotation mysteriously start working, but when I just restarted the app it was broken again (nothing had changed in the code). I'm unable able to reproduce this, so I guess it's a bug after all.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify device rotation rules on view basis. It has to be set on view controller basis. This is how iOS works. Thus, to achieve what you need you have to handle this by yourself. For example, if you're showing your `ARSCNView` as a full screen view, then you can present it inside a custom `UIViewController` sub-class, and set the rotation configuration for that controller.

Setting the supported view rotations for a specific view controller can be implemented in many ways, below are some of them.

---

### Approach #1:

You can set the supported view orientations for any `UIViewController` by overriding your app delegate's method `application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:`.

*Sample code:*

```
// this goes into your AppDelegate...
// Basically, this checks the current visible view controller  type  and  decide 
// what orientations your app supports based on that view controller type (class)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    let visibleViewController = self.topViewController(withRootViewController: window?.rootViewController)

    // Support only portrait orientation for a specific view controller
    if visibleViewController is SomeViewController {
        return .portrait
    }

    // Otherwise, support all orientations (standard behaviour)
    return .allButUpsideDown
}

// This simple helper method is to extract the exact visible  view  controller  at
// the moment, as `window.rootViewController` could have some container controller 
// like `UINavigationController` or so that holds more controllers into it
private func topViewController(withRootViewController rootViewController: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {
    if let rootViewController = rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
        return rootViewController.selectedViewController
    } else if let rootViewController = rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
        return rootViewController.visibleViewController
    } else if let presentedViewController = rootViewController?.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(withRootViewController: presentedViewController)
    }
    return rootViewController
}
```

*Reference:*

[`application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` method documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623107-application?language=swift)

---

### Approach #2:

Sub-class your `UINavigationController` and override the following property:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return self.topViewController?.supportedInterfaceOrientations ?? .all
}
```

Now this always looks into your view controller's `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and set the supported orientations based on the return value. Doing this enables you to simply override this in any view controller you want, setting some custom value.

For example, in `SomeViewController` you could simply add:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
```

*Reference:*

[`supportedInterfaceOrientations` property documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621435-supportedinterfaceorientations)

---

### Approach #3:

If you don't want to sub-class your `UINavigationController` like in approach #2 above, you can set your `SomeViewController` as the navigation controller delegate implementing `navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations(:)`

*Sample code:*

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // ...

    self.navigationController?.delegate = self
}

// MARK: - UINavigationControllerDelegate

func navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations(_ navigationController: UINavigationController) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return navigationController.topViewController?.supportedInterfaceOrientations ?? .all
}
```

*Reference:*

[Matt's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27623947/1363997)

Comment: That would not work for my question. I would like to prevent only the `ARSCNView` from rotating. Your suggestion works only on a *per view controller* basis